# I didn't get a notification about a comment that @-mentioned me

Tags: support

I didn't get a notification about the following comment:

> @MatthewChristopherBartsh many science journalists have absolutely no clue about the topic they are writing about and just regurgitate whatever they are being told. – eps yesterday

[Comment on What does 'a nudge' mean in the context of rocketry?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/51700/what-does-a-nudge-mean-in-the-context-of-rocketry/51702#comment170318_51702)

Comment: `+1` from time to time I feel certain I haven't received a notification about a comment, but I've always dismissed it as "hugh, just one of those things". I also have SE open on more than one device at the same time sometimes and wonder if that contributes.

Comment: Also, if you receive multiple comments on a page, SE only generates a single notification for that page for one of them, not all of them. That part really bugs me. The little red number is 17 (on a good/bad day) but I get only 12 pages to check, meaning there are 5 comments I have to hunt for manually. And in the morning before the coffee has kicked in I'm just Grrrr......